# Capitalize first letter of each word with liquid syntax?

Tags: html, liquid

I am trying to set up SEO in a LocomotiveCMS installation using liquid syntax. I'm trying to code it so that the page title is pulled dynamically using {{ page.title }} and then forcing it to capitalize the first letter of each word.

I tried this:

```
<title>
      {{ page.title | camelcase }} | {{ site.name }}
</title>
```

Based on the liquid syntax documentation here: http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/output#camelize

But it's not working. Using `capitalize` works, but it only capitalizes the first letter of the first word.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried using `camelize` in place of `camelcase` as well but that didn't work either.

Comment: `camelcase` is a [Shopify filter, not a Liquid filter](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/434) - so it won't work in Locomotive CMS.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would suggest to use a plugin to obtain this behavior

`_plugins/_capitalize_all.rb`:

```
require 'liquid'
require 'uri'

# Capitalize all words of the input
module Jekyll
  module CapitalizeAll
    def capitalize_all(words)
      return words.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::CapitalizeAll)
```

Usage:

```
{{ "mein text" | capitalize_all }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! May I ask how to add plugin file in the liquid theme folder?

Comment: @YaoyuYang as far as I remember you just drop it in the `_plugins` directory of your jekyll site and it works

Comment: I see. I am not using Jekyll, I am working on a shopify site, not sure where to add it.

Comment: @YaoyuYang No experience on that, sorry.

Answer (score 37):

There is a way to achieve this using only Liquid syntax. No need for any plugins.

Break down your string of words into an array and use a for loop combined with the capitalize filter to capitalize the first letter of each word. If you appropriately encapsulate this inside a capture statement you are left with the first character in every word capitalized.

```
{% assign words = "Hi, how are you today?" | split: ' ' %}

{% capture titlecase %}
  {% for word in words %}
    {{ word | capitalize }}
  {% endfor %}{% endcapture %}
{{ titlecase }}
```

Output:

> Hi, How Are You Today?

Notice that all of this is on a single line and there is only one occurrence of whitespace within the entire capture statement!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this only the solution despite of using [a custom plug-in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23453152/4058484) or [css-capitalize](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21315850/4058484).

Comment: This is the only thing that has worked for me. Great thinking!

Comment: jesus christ what an awful language

Comment: If you want to avoid ruining intentionally uppercase words, e.g. "HTML", you should change the core of the loop to `{{ word | slice: 0 | upcase -}}{{- word | slice: 1, 999 }}` [not pretty but it works]

Answer (score 16):

how about setting this up with CSS ?

```
title {
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

edit: i did a typo about text-transform, now it is fixed;

Comment: That is not what he wants. He wants that all the words from his title start with a capital letter.

Comment: sorry, i meant: text-transform:capitalize;

Comment: This actually did what I wanted to do, which was title case categories in Jekyll. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Great idea... and luckily capitalize in CSS is not as broken as in Liquid ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to the link you have posted, the camel case works as follows:

```
{{ 'coming-soon' | camelcase }}
```

It takes a string with its words separated with '-' and camelcases it. I have only one question: How are your 'page.title' coming? are its words separated with '-'? or do you have a text like this: "this is the title of my page"? if thats the case, you should replace it with: "this-is-the-title-of-my-page"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses, I actually figured out a workaround right after posting this. Instead of calling `page.title` I am now pulling `page.seo_title` which can be manually entered through the LocomotiveCMS backend with the correct capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

This series of filters has been working for me. You would run into problems if your title had 5 consecutive dashes or dashes where you didn't want the following letter to be capitalized, however.

```
{% assign headerTitle = page.title | split: " " | join: "-----" | camelcase | split: "-----" | join: " " %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: {{ page.title | capitalize }}

It capitalizes only the first word in the sentence.

My first instinct was that this would capitalize every word but it doesnt.

Source: https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#capitalize

Comment: Yeah, this was mentioned in my OP

Comment: I actually had the oposite problem. I didnt want every word in the title to be capitalized. In my case i pull the title from the filename not the front-mater title. And when I do this every word gets capitalized. This is probably a bug from Jekyll. Since its its a surprising convention. The expected title would be the title as it is written in the filename. Im looking into how I can get the actual filename title though. In your case you could just write a liquid loop and have it included if you dont want to clutter up your post code. Or do as I do and just extract the title from the filename.

Answer (score 0):

{{ page.title | capitalize }} | {{ site.name }}

Capitalize now works directing

https://liquidjs.com/filters/capitalize.html